# Why is the present simple tense used for an event that is in the future?

Tags: tense, future-tense, future-time, present-simple, modality

I would like to know the difference between "be going to," the present continuous, and the present simple. We use one of them when we talk about future, but I can't differentiate them. For example:

> The holidays start next week.

Why can't we use:

> - The holidays are going to start next week.
> - The holidays are starting next week.
> - The holidays will start next week.

Comment: Don't feel bad if you can't differ them. I can't, either. They all mean the same thing. :^) (Although the "are going to start" version is my least favorite; it sounds too wordy. But it would be fine for conversation. One could even say: "The holidays will be starting next week," or even, "The holidays are going to be starting next week.") Whichever version you use, I'm looking forward to next week!

Comment: Yeah,me too )Thank you :))So I don't have to differ,they are all the same,It's good !!

Comment: you can use them in speaking. However, if you're looking for a general rule here's some guidelines: use _be going to_, _will_, and _present continuous_ for your **personal definite plans** in future. You can use them for predictions, too based on the signs you percieve as in _it's going to rain_ after you see the clouds in the sky. Use _present simple_ to talk about time tables and events on calender.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A what I posted doesn't really address the OP's concern. She/He's probably aware of the general places that we use these forms; He's looking for a **reason** beyond accepted grammatical structures and not something like _use present simple when the statements are based on present facts, and when these facts are something fixed like a time-table, schedule, calendar_. However, if you think otherwise, you feel free and post a community answer.

Comment: "I would like an answer that addresses all four future tenses mentioned in Reamiel's well laid out question" ← But there aren't any future tenses in the OP's examples. They're all in the present tense.

Comment: @snailplane I'm sorry, but aren't  "going to start...." and "will start..." used to express future? The OP was asking why these forms weren't used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, and if I say "The Lakers play the Bulls tomorrow", I'm using the word *tomorrow* to express future time reference, but that doesn't constitute a future *tense*, which is the kind of distinction we have in form between *have* and *had*.  Time is a semantic concept that can be expressed in lots of different ways (for example with *tomorrow*); tense is a grammatical concept, and not everything that expresses time reference is by definition a tense.

Comment: @snailplane right, you're one of those who argue that English has no tenses ☺. So what about "will" that can be used to express a future event without mentioning a specific time; e.g. "She will go to the prom"

Comment: That'd be silly.  English has a tense system, as I pointed out in my previous comment.  But in your example *will* is a modal auxiliary, and expressing modality is its primary use.  The modal auxiliary *will* is neither sufficient nor necessary to express future time.  In other words, you can express future time without it, and you can use *will* without expressing future time.  If we can't get this straight, we can't possibly answer the question . . .

Comment: @snailplane the argument being that there are only two tenses in the English language, the present and the past, so I was wrong to summarise the four examples as being future tenses. Obviously, I intended that the four forms are used to express future meaning.  But you're right,  I over simplified. I'll remember that next time.

Comment: This is one of the uses of the present simple tenses. You can find more details and examples [here](http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/present_simple).

Comment: "Why can't we use" - err, we do.

Answer (score 11):

Using the present tense for future events indicates *certainty*, *consistency*, and *familiarity*.  In other words, use this to talk about events which will happen, which happen on a regular basis (or are predictable in some way), and about which you have some personal knowledge.

> The holidays start next week.

I know this happens every year, last year I saw it happen in the same way, and I am sure it will happen the same way this year.

> The train leaves in five minutes

I know the train leaves at a specific time, I know that trains usually leave on time, and I have seen the schedule to confirm when the train will leave.

> The gala event starts tomorrow

I have personal knowledge that it is scheduled for tomorrow, I know that events like this usually start on schedule, and I feel comfortable asserting that it will definitely happen.

If any of these three does not exist, there is uncertainty, and the future tense will be more appropriate.

> We get paid on Friday

I know this happens with some consistency and regularity, as I've already received at least one paycheck on Friday.

> We will get paid on Friday

Oops, now there is some doubt.  I *hope* this will happen, but I'm not *sure* it'll happen.

Here's another example: given no other context, consider these two sentences:

> He will make the winning shot of the game in twenty seconds.
>
> He makes the winning shot of the game in twenty seconds.

The first indicates a future condition, but the context is unclear.  Do I really know this will happen?  Probably not.  More likely I'm expressing an opinion, or a personal hope.

But the second sentence, that expresses an odd *certainty*.  The context is either that we are watching a *recording* of the game which I have seen before, or that I'm psychic, and I've already seen this happen with my mental powers.

Comment: You can never *be sure* something will happen in the future, because it hasn't happened yet. Using 'future will', as in *We will get paid on Friday* does not introduce doubt. Besides that, this statement includes all three criteria you have listed for using the present.

Comment: @Clare I would suggest you re-read my answer since you seem to have misunderstood the basic premise.  It's not a question of what actually will or won't happen, but only my own personal level of certainty.

Comment: Your premise is wrong.

Comment: @Clare  A negation without logic or counter-example [is not an argument.  It's just contradiction.](https://youtu.be/kQFKtI6gn9Y?t=76)

Comment: @Andrew No, it isn't.

Comment: Using *will* to speak of the future does add uncertainty.  It's a modal auxiliary after all, and it expresses epistemic modality which is absent from the corresponding clause without modal marking.  That's the primary use of English *will*; the futurive interpretation is secondary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to argue unless you've paid.  :)

Comment: @snailplane I  respect your expertise, and your knowledge on the subject, but I do not perceive any trace of uncertainty in the declaration: `The holidays will start next week.`. Andrew will receive exactly half of the bounty because his answer earned 5 upvotes, but it needed a question on meta to set the ball rolling.   And a long time will pass before I set up a new bounty, users simply do not respond, regardless of the topic under discussion.

Comment: +1 for that brilliant "winning shot" example! It illustrates only one of many possible factors affecting tense choices, but imho it's a very precise distinction which would be *implicitly, subconsciously* recognised by virtually every native speaker. My guess is that not 1 in 100 people could meaningfully explain a difference between *He will arrive in ten minutes* and *He arrives in ten minutes*. But in yours, if asked to say which version was "real-time" reporting, and which was said ***after*** the "winning shot", they'd ***all*** make the same choice (without necessarily knowing why).

Answer (score 8):

When we are **sure about the event/things in the future**, the present tense is okay.

> The holidays start next week - it's **fixed** that the holidays are coming next week. It's similar to the Valentine's Day **is** on February 14 and not *will be on**.

Some more examples -

> The train **leaves** in 5 minutes - the train is scheduled to depart at that time.
>   
>   The gala event **starts** tomorrow - it's fixed that it'll begin tomorrow.

Comment: Isn't it correct to say "The train will leave in 5 minutes"? why?

Comment: @Reamiel. That's correct for the train and may be even for the gala event as they are still likely to get postpone/delayed. Since you asked about the holidays, for example Christmastide that has fixed dates/days, it preferably takes the present tense.

Comment: Thank you @Maulik .What about "I'm meeting Susan this evening " Can I say "I meet Susan this evening " Because our meeting is arranged ,fixed to be this evening .

Comment: You can say "I meet Susan this evening," but the **tone** is different. It sounds more formal, almost foreboding. If Susan is a good friend of mine, I'm more likely to say, "I'm meeting Susan this evening," or "I'll be meeting Susan this evening." But if Susan is a coworker I don't get along with very well, or an ex-wife, or a competitor in some bitter rivalry, I might go with the more icy, "I meet Susan this evening." But it's verb-dependent, too. Say I'm in a band; the drummer asks, "Are we open on the 16th?" I can answer: "No – we play at the nightclub that evening." Nothing icy about that.

Comment: @J.R. You can also say, "Susan and I meet on Tuesdays and Thursdays." without sounding formal or foreboding.