# Should I use "closes" or "is closing" or "is going to close"?

Tags: tense

> Let's walk quickly because the shop (closes/is closing/is going to close) in ten minutes.

These choices seem very confusing to me, because they are close in the meaning. I do not know whether to choose, in my opinion I'm going to choose **is closing** but I don't know why? So I need to understand what is going on in this sentence.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use present simple **closes** about a general truth (something that always happens) or about a scheduled event

> Ice melts if you heat it - *general truth*
>   My flight leaves at 9:45 - *scheduled event.*

You can use present continuous **be closing** about something that is happening right now, or something that is planned or intended to happen soon.

> I am writing a book - *right now*
>   I am leaving tomorrow - *intent*

You can use **be going to *infinitive*** for something that will happen or intended to happen: usually it means soon, but could be some time away.

> There is going to be a full moon tonight - *will happen*
>   I am going to make dinner soon - *intent*
>   We are all going to die one day - *will happen eventually*

You can also use **will *infinitive*** for something that will definitely happen or you intend to happen at any time in the future.

> The sun will rise at 5:43am - *will happen*
>   I will go to America one day - *intent*

All of the versions that you have suggested would be OK, but the best would be

> Let's walk quickly because the shop closes in ten minutes. - *scheduled*
>   Let's walk quickly because the shop is going to close in ten minutes. - *will happen soon*
>   Let's walk quickly because the shop will close in ten minutes. - *will definitely happen*

These three examples are all equally good: the circumstances might affect which one you choose to use. **is going to close** is slightly less formal. There is not much difference between the other two, unless you want to distinguish between *scheduled* and *will definitely happen*.

The weakest is this version, because it's not happening now and it's not something that you plan or intend.

> Let's walk quickly because the shop is closing in ten minutes

Comment: I disagree that "is closing" is weakest. Perhaps it's a regional thing, but the "is closing" form is the one I hear most often in announcements by store staff. Perhaps because, as "is closing" invokes the sense of "right now", this choice invokes a sense of urgency not necessarily present in the others. - Not only is it going to close, the closure is immanent and we need to hurry. - If you're looking for that sense of urgency/immediacy, I think using the "is closing" is a perfectly fine stylistic choice.

Comment: "imminent" rather than "immanent" perhaps...

Comment: @R.M., Firstly, this answer is intended to explain the general rules that apply to tense selection, and acknowledges that these rules aren't rigid: I say that "is closing" is weakest (from the point of view of the rules), not wrong. As far as applying the rules goes, it's a question of perspective. In my final sentence, I say "It's not something that **you** [the shopper] plan or intend". When store staff make an announcement, their perspective is different: it **is** something that **they** plan or intend. I do agree that you could also use this form to give a sense of urgency/immediacy..

Answer (score 12):

In *this case,* I think all are correct and mean almost the same thing that you need to hurry to reach the shop before it shuts down.

However, a *little nuance* I can *(forcefully!)* think of is that when you use 'closes,' you are talking about the 'regular closing time.' On the other hand, if you say 'is closing,' it **may** mean that you just got the news, and the shop is closing not at its regular time.

As I said in [my answer here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/why-is-the-present-simple-tense-used-for-an-event-that-is-in-the-future/15213#15213), if the event is *definitely* going to happen (or it's a regular affair as in trains schedules), using the base verb in present tense is fine.

> Hurry, the shop closes at 8 p.m. ~ regular timing 
>  Hurry, the shop is closing at 8 a.m. ~ **maybe,** you know that it's not its usual time and the shop is closing early.

**But again,** as I said, this is exaggeration. In my opinion, in your case, *broadly*, all three can work.

Comment: What's the difference between is going to close, and is closing in this sentence?

Comment: **before it gets closed** is definitely not an idiomatic expression about a shop... unless it is selling something illegal and the police will soon come along to close it.

Comment: @JavaLatte edited. If still not okay, let me know what's correct there.