# What's the most neutral future tense in English?

Tags: grammar, future-tense

Without the sense of "Willingness" or "Intend" or whatnot, what form has the most neutral future meaning in a daily conversation?

Someone told me that the "Be going to" would be the one, but he was not a very reliable guy, so I couldn't trust what he had to say 100% sure. Furthermore, I usually watch some TV series which has been translated in English from the original source, my language; And those things make me think that the one is nothing but "Subject'll be -ing". I've seen so many times that the casual future tenses have been translated into this one.

So, what do you think? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "neutral" future tense?  Are you referring to *likelihood* or *desirability*, or something else entirely?

Comment: @Andrew I meant something you can use in many different kinds of future-tense-sentences the most. Something that could cause the least problems if you replace the other verb words with it.

Comment: I still don't really get what you mean, or how the accepted answer relates to the question.  In your own language are there future tense modals that are not neutral?  Could you give an example of one?

Comment: @Andrew "The plane takes off at 3 a.m." could be rephrased like "The plane is going to take off at 3 a.m." right? But you can't make "We're going to spend the summer abroad." into "We spend the summer abroad." Unlike English, my language has 'future tense' instead of future modal. So almost every future case in English which is described by "be going to", "be ing", "be to", "will", "will be ing", "Present verb + future time adverb", and such could be translated into just one word. And thinking backward, my language to English, is so much frustrating work sometimes.

Comment: @Andrew Prescriptivists tend to distinguish between, e.g., "I will pay my taxes", indicating some level of willingness, and "I shall pay my taxes", indicating simply that a tax-paying event is going to occur at some point in the future. See, e.g., [Shall and will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will) (Wikipedia).

Comment: @DavidRicherby  You'll note the Wikipedia article suggests the differences between *shall* and *will* are either outdated, or confined to strict legal interpretation, " Due to heavy misuse,  [shall] can be ambiguous."  In casual speech there is no consistent semantic difference between *will* and *shall*, but only information that the speaker is from an increasingly-rare dialect where *shall* is normally used.   In my area, few if any would say casually, "We *shall* go to the beach this afternoon," to indicate firmness of purpose, but rather, "Let's definitely go to the beach this afternoon."

Comment: @Andrew That's why I said "Prescriptivists tend to distinguish between..." rather than "There is a difference between..." (Indeed, neither of the answers even mentions "shall".)

Comment: @DavidRicherby  fair enough.  As with many things you have to evaluate based on context.  See my answer below for my thoughts on the difference between using and not using a future-tense modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both *will VERB* and *be going to VERB* are neutral in certain contexts, perhaps even in most contexts.

For instance, *it will rain* and *it is going to rain* are completely neutral; no value judgements, no implications about intentions.

Likewise, *I will fail this test* and *I am going to fail this test* both say nothing about the speaker's interests or intentions.

This holds true even for actions which the speaker could conceivably intend to perform. *I'll go to the store after this show ends* and *I am going to go to the store after this show ends* don't necessarily imply anything about the speaker's ambition. That is to say, either sentence could be spoken whether the speaker was excited to go to the store, or being forced to go to the store by someone else.

However, in some contexts, using the future tense is a way of making a promise.  *I will try my hardest* and *I am never going to stop* are often said to assure the listener of our intentions.  When the future tense is used for a promise, rather than a prediction, it does imply something about our intentions. But both forms can be used for making promises, so there's no important difference there, either.

Comment: As also is the so-called present simple, if the time is established in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I think at least part of your confusion is because you misunderstand the common nuance of the present tense, which is to report events that are *natural* and/or *routine*.  For example:

> The plane **takes off** at 3 am

is fine because it's natural and routine for the plane to do so.  It's part of a defined schedule, even if it's a one-time event.  Its not much different from saying "the sun rises at 6 am" or "I go to school at 8 am (every morning)".  It's more a *statement of fact* than a forecast.

On the other hand

> The plain **will/is going to take off** at 3 am

*is* a prediction of a future event.  It includes some measure of doubt, because no one can truly know the future.  I talk about this in a [previous ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/why-is-the-present-simple-tense-used-for-an-event-that-is-in-the-future/115184#115184) with regard to sporting events:

> He **will make** the winning shot of the game in twenty seconds.

is a hopeful observation, but

> He **makes** the winning shot of the game in twenty seconds.

is *prophetic*. It's as if you have a crystal ball or some other occult device that allows you to accurately foretell events that haven't happened yet.

This is the reason you can't go back from

> **We're going to** spend the summer abroad next year

to

> **We spend** the summer abroad next year

because the two don't mean the same thing. The first is a *prediction*, while the second is a *prophecy*.

I don't know if the future tense in your native language includes a nuance of doubt, or if, by using the future tense, you express events that you believe to be certain.  Nevertheless, if you want to accurately translate both the meaning and the nuance of these kind of English phrases, you may have to add some uncertain element.

It all depends on the context.  Something like:

> In a few minutes the clock **will strike** three

is still pretty certain, despite the use of "will".  You have to take into account the relatively likelihood of the event, if you want to accurately understand/translate the nuance.

Comment: So your point is, in English, future tense(+modal) always have some nuance of doubt, ambition, intention, prediction or etc? In other words, there's no case that any of future form indicates just future itself?

Comment: I would say rather that the usual English modals like *will* and *be going to* are the "normal" future tense that exists in other languages.  For whatever reason English also allows the present tense to be used for future events in a limited way, that suggests more certainty.   But others might disagree, and point out various exceptions to this pattern.

Comment: I strongly agree that there is no single answer. Certain forms are *mostly* neutral in *many* contexts, but nothing you can rely on.